# How to identify if a record in a database has data in a certain column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm wondering how to get figure out if a record in a database has all of its fields filled out or if it is missing some. I have a form that allows optional data to be submitted. If that data has been submitted, I would like to display it, if not I want to display something different.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about in rails/pseudo-code.

```
<% @content.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
  <%= c.email %>
  <%= if(c.phone_number.exists()) %>
    <%= c.phone_number %>
  <% else %>
    Phone number hidden
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for non-null object:

```
 <% if @model.attribute %>
   <%= @model.attribute %>
 <% else %>
   Do something else
 <% end %>
```

Or present object (non-empty string, list...)

```
<% if @model.attribute.present? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```